# Click not registering

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've added a bunch of buttons using Jquery, all of them in the same class, and I'm trying to have them do something when clicked. I have a simple on click function for them right now that just logs the word "clicked" to the console, but it is not registering any of my clicks. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Minesweeper</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="dimensions">
        Width:  <input type="Width" id="width"><br/>
        Height: <input type="Height" id="height"><br/>
        <button type="button" id="new-game" onclick="newGame()">Create</button>
    </div>
    <div id="board"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
function newGame() {
    var cols = $("#width").val();
    var rows = $("#height").val();

    if (cols < 8 || rows < 8) {
        return;
    }else if (cols > 40 || rows > 30) {
        return;
    }
    boardClear();
    possibleBombs = (rows * cols) - 1;
    numBombs = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j <= cols; j++) {
            if (numBombs < possibleBombs) {
                q = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
                if (q == 0) {
                    numBombs += 1;
                }
                $("#board").append('<button type="button" class="tile" data-row = ' + i + 'data-col = ' + j + 'data-contains = ' + q + '></button>');
            } 
            else {
                $("#board").append('<button type="button" class="tile" data-row = ' + i + 'data-col = ' + j + 'data-contains = 1 ></button>');
            }
        }
        $("#board").append("<br/>");
    }
    $(".tile").width(100/cols);
    $(".tile").height(100/rows);
    console.log("bombs: " + numBombs, "possible: " + possibleBombs);
}

$(".tile").on('click', function() {
    $(this).css("color", "black");
    console.log("clicked");
});

function boardClear() {
    $("#board").empty();
}
```

You can see that my `$(".tile")` on click function has the word "clicked" logged to console, but that never happens when I click on one.

I have tried wrapping the on click function in `$(document).ready(function(){})`, but it still does not work.

Comment: `$("tile")` But you do not have `<tile>`s anywhere, maybe you want `$('.tile')` (also use event delegation instead)

Comment: Not sure how that happened, since I had it as `.tile` before, but that does not fix the problem.

Comment: `(also use event delegation instead)`, did you try that too?

Comment: Move your jquery and script tag out the `head` to just above the closing `body` tag.

Comment: @AshleyBrown That doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I'm looking up what event delegation is and trying to implement it.

Comment: Your on click listener should be placed within the newGame() function after the buttons have been added.

Comment: @MichaelvE I tried that earlier and I guess it didn't work because for some reason I had change it to `tile` instead of `.tile` but that does indeed work. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use

```
$(document).on('click', '.tile', function() {
```

Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on(). To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, perform event binding inside a document ready handler for elements that are in the HTML markup on the page. If new HTML is being injected into the page, select the elements and attach event handlers after the new HTML is placed into the page.

I made the change in your HTML and tested it and works as expected. Cheers!

Comment: Important to note, this method is known as [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).